# Old CALayer animation stays applied

Tags: ios, core-animation

I have a weird problem with CALayer animations. List of actions which lead to this:

- I add an opacity animation to a `CALayer` (`CAKeyframeAnimation`). FillMode being `kCAFillModeForwards` or `kCAFillModeRemoved` makes no difference.
- To resize that layer (after a screen rotation for example) I pause the animation at time `X`, set the `CALayer` `beginTime` and `timeOffset` to `0` (just to be sure) and call `removeAllAnimations()` on that layer.
- I update the `frame` of the layer.
- Then I add the new opacity animation.

Problem is: The layer has the correct size and the opacity animations only *after* time `X`, before that it's stuck at full opacity and has its old size! Which is really strange, because the size was never animated and I changed the size while no animations were applied to the layer.

Also all superlayers have `beginTime == 0` and `timeOffset == 0`.

Why does that happen?

Comment: Can you post a minimal example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why this fails. If the layout changes, e.g. with a screen rotation, the OS automatically animates all layers, UIViews, etc. to their new states via "actions". They are added to already existing animations, completely ignoring if the user has already their own animation added. Problem is: This works only with the most simple cases, if you have a little bit more complex animations your animations get broken.
To stop the OS from interfering with your animations just assign your `CALayer` `actions` property to

```
["bounds": NSNull(),
 "contents": NSNull(),
 "contentsGravity": NSNull(),
 "contentsScale": NSNull(),
 "fontSize": NSNull(),
 "hidden": NSNull(),
 "onLayout": NSNull(),
 "onOrderIn": NSNull(),
 "onOrderOut": NSNull(),
 "position": NSNull(),
 "speed": NSNull(),
 "timeOffset": NSNull()]
```

Which blocks most actions from being added by the OS (this list may be incomplete).

If you read tutorials and documentation for Core Animation you won't find any warnings to look out for "actions" animations interfering with your stuff, so it's not an obvious solution, but it works.